# In VSTS, what is the best way to rebase a dev branch to master when dev branch has policies

Tags: git, azure-devops, rebase, branching-and-merging

Due to policies in VSTS can't push branch updates, these can only be done through pull requests. I've tried two techniques:

1. create 'rebase' branch off dev, rebase to master, merge with dev branch using a PR.
2. turn off (suspend) the dev policy in order to do the push after doing rebase on dev branch.

The first approach creates a much messier log history (lots more commits); so I'm leaning towards promoting the second approach. I don't like the idea of suspending a policy.

Anyone got a better suggestion?

Comment: Does `dev` branch has branch policy? And what's the purpose to rebase `dev` to `master` branch, do you want to apply the changhes from `dev` branch into `master` branch or else?

Comment: `rebase` is to get hotfixes applied to `master` onto `dev` branch.

Comment: @Richard K, Really thanks for sharing your solution her, if possible, you could mark your solution as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use approach 1, but when doing pull request don't `squash commit`s. That way `commit`s to `master` branch will appear on `dev` branch and it's obvious what has been done.

Comment: You can mark your own answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set certain privileged users to be exempt from policy enforcement. It's branch-level security setting.

Comment: Realised the first approach to `rebase` using a branch off `dev` was not giving the results because was doing a `squash merge`. By removing `squash` was able to get the result I was after using approach 1.

Comment: Exempting people from policies will only work if they never do work that requires them to comply. Can't assume that at this stage.